# GWT/GXT containers render position issues

Tags: gwt, gxt

While trying to insert absolute positioned HorizontalContainer into other container, I came upon weird issue. This absolute container pushes his next sibling by its width, if siblings are still being rendered (has a mask set).

Example:.

```
//parent container, holding all the widgets
HorizontalLayoutContainer hlc;

//widgets that are inserted into hlc container from the start
HBoxLayoutContainer hbox1;
HBoxLayoutContainer hbox2;
HBoxLayoutContainer hbox3;

//container that's inserted into hlc onMouseOver event. It can be inserted while hlc hboxes are still being rendered
HorizontalLayoutContainer panelContainer = new HorizontalLayoutContainer(); 
panelContainer.getElement().getStyle().setZIndex(13);
panelContainer.getElement().getStyle().setPosition(Position.ABSOLUTE);
panelContainer.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(55, Unit.PX);
panelContainer.getElement().getStyle().setHeight(18, Unit.PX);
panelContainer.getElement().getStyle().setFloat(Float.LEFT);
```

Now let's say a user hovers mouse over hlc container, which has hboxes1-3, however some of them has a mask set (data is still loading), like `hbox1.mask()`. onMouseOver event `panelContainer` is inserted into hlc:

```
hlc.insert(panelContainer, 0, new HorizontalLayoutData(55, 18));
```

However, since hboxes are still being rendered, panelContainer pushes hbox1 by 55px (its length) to the right. Even if it has `position:absolute;`.

```
                left:55px; should be left: 0px;
                -->
|panleContainer|hbox1|hbox2|hbox3|
```

Any suggestions how should I properly insert `panelContainer`? Why is absolute positioning being ignored?

**Note:**

If I wait for hboxes to be rendered, panelContainer is inserted properly, hbox1 is not pushed.

**Clarification to avoid xy problem:**

**Short summary**: add an absolutely positioned box (for clarity, let's call it DragBox) which has a predefined width to an existing container (WidgetBox). WidgetBox is a HorizontalLayoutContainer which has 2 or 3 HBoxLayoutContainers. WidgetBox children (HBoxLayoutContainers) have widths of percentages. Example: if WidgetBox has 2 children, their widths are 0.3 and 0.7, if 3 children, then widths are 0.3, 0.4, 0.3;

WidgetBox is sized by its parent (SimpleContainer->VerticalLayoutContainer->WidgetBox).

**Expecting:** When a mouse is hovered over any WidgetBox container, a new item (DragBox) is added as a first element of the WidgetBox. It should not affect WidgetBox children in anyway. It should act as an absolute (within WidgetBox bounds) box.

**Result:** If WidgetBox or its parent's layout is forced (through forceLayout()), then DragBox affects first WidgetBox child. If forceLayout() is not used, DragBox does not affect WidgetBox children.

Comment: Have you tried using a CssFloatLayoutContainer instead of the HorizontalLayoutContainer?

Comment: I did, unfortunately it did not help. I am using forceLayout() on hlc container, and it seems this causes issues. Sadly, if I am not using it, content in hlc container is badly formatted (alignment etc).

Comment: Another way could be using a HtmlLayoutContainer.

Comment: How does HtmlLayoutContainer go into this? That's a completely different container from what I am using. I would have to write custom HTML template and rewrite quite a bit of code to use it and I still would not get any guarantees that it would work. Or is that what you meant?

Comment: If you are specifying styles through CSS manually, you really should consider a container that leaves the styling to plain CSS - in order for HBoxLC or HLC to actually do its job, it must adjust the same sorts of styles that you are setting. Those interactions are likely causing these issues - if you don't want the container to position the child, you shouldn't use a container designed to do so.

Comment: @ColinAlworth, Thanks for the tip, what container would you suggest? Aren't all horizontal GXT containers positioning their children? Would you care to elaborate your comment in an answer?

Comment: I'll take a stab at an answer, if you clarify the question - it currently suffers from a bit of an x/y problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you are asking how to do something specific within a specific set of containers, can you clarify by saying what you want to achieve exactly? What is sized by its parent, what has a concrete size, and how should adding the new item affect the other relative sizes, etc.

Comment: @ColinAlworth added more information on my issue. If it's not enough, then I suppose my problem is too specific. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since forceLayout() in my case is used only to ensure proper WidgetBox children (see my edit) content formatting, I don't want to force children to be laid out for widgetBox.

To avoid this, I forced layout on each child of widgetBox instead of a parent.

Example:.

```
HorizontalLayoutContainer (parent) 
  -> HorizontalLayoutContainer (child 1, removed/added on mouseOver/Out)
  -> HBoxLayoutContainer (child 2)
  -> ...
```

I used to force layout on parent, like `parent.forceLayout()` which would force children to be laid out and parent container would be resized.

To avoid, as mentioned, I force layout on each child separately:

```
for(int i = 0; i < parent.getWidgetCount(); i++) {
    if (parent.getWidget(i) instanceof ResizeContainer) {
        ResizeContainer widget = (ResizeContainer) parent.getWidget(i);
        widget.forceLayout();
    }
}
```